# Oracle SQL join date dimension table with another table on date value

Tags: sql, oracle, max, left-join

I have a date dimension table containing all dates and another table containing the value of items at specific dates.
E.g
(a) Date_Dim table

```
|Full_Date  |  
|-----------|
| ....      |
|1-jan-2021 |
|2-Jan-2021 |
|3-jan-2021 |
| ...       |
```

(b) Item_value table

```
|P_Date      | ITEM  | Value  |
|-----------:|:------|-------:|
|20-Dec-2020 |AA1    |9       |
|1-jan-2021  |AA1    |10      |
|1-jan-2021  |AA2    |100     |
| ...        | ...   | ...    |
```

I am trying to build a fact table containing the latest value of every item in the item_value table for every date in the date_dim table. i.e the value of the items every day.
e.g

```
|Full_date   | ITEM   | Value |
|-----------:|-------:|------:|
|31-Dec-2020 |AA1     | 9     |
|31-Dec-2020 |AA2     | null  |
|1-Jan-2021  |AA1     | 10    |
|1-Jan-2021  |AA2     | 100   |
|2-Jan-2021  |AA1     | 10    |
|2-Jan-2021  |AA2     | 100   |
|3-Jan-2021  |AA1     | 10    |
|3-Jan-2021  |AA2     | 100   |
|4-Jan-2021  |AA1     | 10    |
|4-Jan-2021  |AA2     | 100   |
```

How can this query be built, please?
I have tried the following but not working

select full_date,p_date,item,value
from dim_date
left outer join item_value on full_date=p_date;

Not sure whether max(p_date) over (partition by ...) will work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a partitioned outer join and then aggregate:

```sql
WITH date_dim ( full_date ) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2020-12-31' + LEVEL - 1 AS full_Date
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2020-12-31' + LEVEL - 1 <= DATE '2021-01-04'
)
SELECT item,
       full_date,
       MAX( value ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY p_date ) AS value
FROM   date_dim d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN item_value i
       PARTITION BY ( i.item )
       ON ( d.full_date >= i.p_date )
GROUP BY item, full_date
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_value ( P_Date, ITEM, Value ) AS
SELECT DATE '2020-12-20', 'AA1',   9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 'AA1',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2021-01-01', 'AA2', 100 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ITEM | FULL_DATE | VALUE
> :--- | :-------- | ----:
> AA1  | 31-DEC-20 |     9
> AA1  | 01-JAN-21 |    10
> AA1  | 02-JAN-21 |    10
> AA1  | 03-JAN-21 |    10
> AA1  | 04-JAN-21 |    10
> AA2  | 31-DEC-20 |  null
> AA2  | 01-JAN-21 |   100
> AA2  | 02-JAN-21 |   100
> AA2  | 03-JAN-21 |   100
> AA2  | 04-JAN-21 |   100
> ```

*Note: You do not need to store the `date_dim` dimension table; it can be generated on-the-fly and will reduce the need to perform (expensive) IO operations reading the table from the hard disk.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3bbe67410efcb0f0465511d0f47911d2)*

Answer (score 0):

You may simple add a *validity interval* for you `ITEM` table using the analtical function `LEAD`

```
select  
P_DATE,
lead(P_DATE-1,1,(select max(full_date) from date_dim)) over (partition by ITEM order by P_DATE) P_DATE_TO,
ITEM, VALUE
from item_value
;

P_DATE              P_DATE_TO           ITE      VALUE
------------------- ------------------- --- ----------
20.12.2020 00:00:00 31.12.2020 00:00:00 AA1          9
01.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00 AA1         10
01.01.2021 00:00:00 04.01.2021 00:00:00 AA2        100
```

In some case this is enough for your use case as you can query the `VALUE` of a specific  `ITEM` on a given `date` with

```
select VALUE from item_value_hist h where ITEM = 'AA2' 
                                          and <query_date> BETWEEN h.P_DATE and h.P_DATE_TO
```

Note, that the *validity interval* is *inclusive*, as we for `P_DATE_TO` subtract one day from the adjacent `P_DATE`. You should take some care is the `DATE`s  have a time component.

If you want the ITEM per DAY overview you must first add the *missing early history* with the `VALUE` of `NULL`

```
select 
(select min(full_date) from date_dim) P_DATE,  min(P_DATE)-1  P_DATE_TO, ITEM, null VALUE
from item_value
group by ITEM
having min(P_DATE) > (select min(full_date) from date_dim)

P_DATE              P_DATE_TO           ITE VALUE
------------------- ------------------- --- -----
31.12.2020 00:00:00 31.12.2020 00:00:00 AA2
```

Than simple *outer join* to your dimension table matching all day from your *validity interval*

```
with item as (
select  
P_DATE,
lead(P_DATE-1,1,(select max(full_date) from date_dim)) over (partition by ITEM order by P_DATE) P_DATE_TO,
ITEM, VALUE
from item_value
union all
select 
/* add the missing early history without a VALUE */
(select min(full_date) from date_dim) P_DATE,  min(P_DATE)-1  P_DATE_TO, ITEM, null VALUE
from item_value
group by ITEM
having min(P_DATE) > (select min(full_date) from date_dim)
)
select dt.full_date, item.ITEM, item.VALUE from item
join date_dim dt
on dt.full_date between item.P_DATE and item.P_DATE_TO
order by item.ITEM, dt.full_date

FULL_DATE           ITE      VALUE
------------------- --- ----------
31.12.2020 00:00:00 AA1          9
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA1         10
02.01.2021 00:00:00 AA1         10
03.01.2021 00:00:00 AA1         10
04.01.2021 00:00:00 AA1         10
31.12.2020 00:00:00 AA2           
01.01.2021 00:00:00 AA2        100
02.01.2021 00:00:00 AA2        100
03.01.2021 00:00:00 AA2        100
04.01.2021 00:00:00 AA2        100
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. Cross join dates and items. If you don't have an item table (which you should), join distinct items from your item_value table.
2. Get the value in the `FROM` clause with `OUTER APPLY` or in the `SELECT` clause with a subquery using `FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY`.

The query:

```
select 
  d.full_date,
  i.item,
  (
    select iv.value
    from Item_value iv
    where iv.item = i.item
    and iv.p_date <= d.full_date
    order by iv.p_date desc
    fetch first row only
  ) as value
from dim_date d
cross join (select distinct item from item_value) i
order by d.full_date, i.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the full list of dates and items using `cross join` followed by a `left join` to bring in the existing values.  Then you can use `last_value()` or `lag()` to fill in the values:

```
select d.p_date, i.item, 
       coalesce(v.value,
                lag(v.value ignore nulls) over (partition by i.item order by d.p_date)
               ) as value
from date_dim d cross join
     (select distinct iv.item from item_value iv) i left join
     item_value iv
     on iv.p_date = d.p_date and iv.item = i.item;
```

You can also do this using a `join` by adding an "end" date to the values table:

```
select d.p_date, i.item, 
       coalesce(v.value,
                lag(v.value ignore nulls) over (partition by i.item order by d.p_date)
               ) as value
from date_dim d cross join
     (select distinct iv.item from item_value iv) i left join
     (select iv.*,
             lead(p_date) over (partition by item order by p_date) as next_p_date
      from item_value iv
     ) iv
     on i.item = iv.item and
        d.p_date >= iv.p_date and
        (iv.next_p_date is null or d.p_date < iv.next_p_date);
```